# Limit sms-chars & counting in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sms

I try to add a char-limiter for an html-textarea in a given javascript. Further I like to add a total-remaining-counter. But my code is not working.

Have you got an idea, where I am wrong?

```
maxLen=640;
if(text.length>maxLen)
{document.getElementById("message").value=text.substring(0,maxLen);}

else
{document.getElementsByClassName("totalcounter").value=maxLen-text.length;}
```

[Demo on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/doschni/wmdwehdL/) -> my problem are the lines 62-70.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution as following:

**Limit SMS-text after 5 Messages (shown as 1 on Mobilephones) and add a total remaining counter**

```
<!-- maxLen GSM7: 765 chars = 5 Messages
<!-- maxLen GSM7EX: 765 chars - (number of used "gsm7bitExChar"-Chars * 2)= 5 Messages  
<!-- maxLen UTF16: 335 chars = 5 Messages     

if(encoding == 'GSM_7BIT'){
     maxLen=764;

if(text.length>maxLen)
{
  document.getElementById("message").value=text.substring(0,maxLen);
}
else
{
  document.getElementsByClassName("totalcounter")[0].innerHTML=maxLen-text.length;
}   

  return count = {
    encoding: encoding,
    length: length,
    per_message: per_message,
    remaining: remaining,
    messages: messages
    }

}; <!-- close if encoding 1

  if(encoding == 'GSM_7BIT_EX'){
    maxLen=762;

if(text.length>maxLen)
{
  document.getElementById("message").value=text.substring(0,maxLen);
}
else
{
  document.getElementsByClassName("totalcounter")[0].innerHTML=maxLen-text.length;
}   

  return count = {
    encoding: encoding,
    length: length,
    per_message: per_message,
    remaining: remaining,
    messages: messages
    }

};<!-- close if encoding 2

if(encoding == 'UTF16'){
    maxLen=334;

 if(text.length>maxLen)
{
  document.getElementById("message").value=text.substring(0,maxLen);
}
else
{
  document.getElementsByClassName("totalcounter")[0].innerHTML=maxLen-text.length;
}   

  return count = {
    encoding: encoding,
    length: length,
    per_message: per_message,
    remaining: remaining,
    messages: messages
    }

};<!-- close if encoding 3
```

Hope this helps also other people. **[Solution on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/doschni/wmdwehdL/1/)**

Special thanks to [danxexe](https://github.com/danxexe/sms-counter)

Answer (score 1):

did you try attribute maxlength of textarea?

```
<textarea maxlength="50">
```

Comment: This is not useful, because in this given sms javascript are some different encodings. With normal chars, it counts normal, with another standard, a single char (for example °) count as 30 chars.

Comment: i don't understand. I'm trying it right now and it has no difference. Still count as 1 char O.o

Comment: You're right, but the encoding type has changed to unicode, witch reduces one sms from 160 chars to 70 chars (difference is 90 not 30, sorry)

Answer (score 0):

to make your code working , move if else block before "return"(shown below) and use `document.getElementsByClassName("totalcounter")[0].innerHTML=maxLen-text.length;` instead of `document.getElementsByClassName("totalcounter").value=maxLen-text.length;`

```
maxLen=640;
        if(text.length>maxLen)
    {
        document.getElementById("message").value=text.substring(0,maxLen);
    }
        else
    {
        document.getElementsByClassName("totalcounter")[0].innerHTML=maxLen-text.length;
    }     
  return count = {
    encoding: encoding,
    length: length,
    per_message: per_message,
    remaining: remaining,
    messages: messages
  };
```

[working JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yfvxrftt/)

Comment: Thanks! It's working as I asked the question. But I just realise, that there should not go out more than 640 chars: truly there should not be sent more than 5 messages! (or a limiter/counter for every encoding type)